# explode function in pyspark

Tags: apache-spark-sql, pyspark

My data frame looks like -

```
+----+----+-------------+
|col1|col2|         col3|
+----+----+-------------+
|   1|   A|[[[1, 2, 3]]]|
|   2|   B|   [[[3, 5]]]|
+----+----+-------------+
```

I want data frame -

```
+----+----+----+
|col1|col2|col3|
+----+----+----+
|   1|   A|   1|
|   1|   A|   2|
|   1|   A|   3|
|   2|   B|   3|
|   2|   B|   5|
+----+----+----+
```

My code is like -

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import explode
df = spark.createDataFrame([(1, "A", [[[1,2,3]]]), (2, "B", [[[3,5]]])],["col1", "col2", "col3"])
df1 = df.withColumn("col3", explode(df.col3))
df1.show()
```

But the output is -

```
+----+----+-----------+
|col1|col2|       col3|
+----+----+-----------+
|   1|   A|[[1, 2, 3]]|
|   2|   B|   [[3, 5]]|
+----+----+-----------+
```

How to solve it using explode function in pyspark

Comment: `df.withColumn('col3', explode(df.col3[0][0])).show()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are having `nested array` we need to `flatten nested arrays` by using **flatten** in built function first then use **explode** function.

**`Try with:`**

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
df.withColumn("col3",explode(flatten(flatten(col("col3"))))).show()
#+----+----+----+
#|col1|col2|col3|
#+----+----+----+
#|   1|   A|   1|
#|   1|   A|   2|
#|   1|   A|   3|
#|   2|   B|   3|
#|   2|   B|   5|
#+----+----+----+
```

---

Other way would be traversing through `nested array[0][0]` and do `explode`on inner most array as mentioned in comment by [`jxc`](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9510729/jxc).

```
df.withColumn("col3", explode(col("col3")[0][0])).show()
```